# What does {{{…}}} mean in Swift?

Tags: swift, swift-playground

I wrote the following code in playground.

```
struct Product {

    var randomNumber: Int?
    init?(number: Int){
        if number <3 {return nil}
        randomNumber=number

    }
}
var mug = Product(number: 5)        // {{{…}}}
```

In the output on the right I get {{{…}}} as indicated by the comment. What do this symbols mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a shorthand notation that indicates different levels of wrapping. Xcode is just telling you what's in the variable `mug` The outermost curly-brackets are the wrapping around the optional. The second level of brackets wraps around your struct properties and the third level of wrapping is an optional wrapped around your `randomNumber` property. You can visualize it by doing this.

```
var mug = Product(number: 5) // {{{...}}}
var amug = mug! // {{Some 5}}
var bmug = mug!.randomNumber // {Some 5}
var cmug = mug!.randomNumber! // 5
```

Answer (score 2):

{...} means you are getting an optional result from Product containing another optional randomNumber . You can use "if let" to safely unwrap your optionals as follow:

```
if let mug = Product(number: 5) {
    if let mugRandomNumber = mug.randomNumber {
        println(mugRandomNumber)   // 5
    }
}
```